# Functional Principal Component Analysis - Interpreting FPCA Scores

Tags: python, data-analysis, pca

I am working with a dataset which reflects participants in a weight loss management trial (longitudinal data). The dataset consists of 1139 participants and four observations of weight (sparse data). The observations of weight were collated on four different days. The objective of my work is to apply Functional Principal Component Analysis to the dataset to uncover distinct trajectories of change in weight (trajectory modelling).

In modelling, I have uncovered four distinct trajectories. FPC1 accounts for 96.59% of explained variance. FPC2, 2.25% and FPC3/ FPC4 account for a combined 1.15% of variance. FPC1 exhibits an upward trajectory, this demonstrating weight gain over the trial. The mean function reflects initial weight loss in the trial followed by consistent weight regain thereafter. See the below image.

[image: FPC1 versus Mean Function]

I produced participant level FPC Scores for FPC1. These scores demonstrates participant level contribution to the variance or pattern uncovered in FPC1. See the below table.

[image: Participant FPC Scores]

Taking participant 1180 as an example, they scored strong positive FPC score in FPC1. This suggests that they strongly correlate or contribute to the pattern uncovered in FPC1. However, observing their functional data, their pattern exhibits differently to that of the component.

[image: Participant 1180 versus FPC1]

My understanding of FPCA would be that this can occur in that whilst a participant may score a strong positive FPC score, they may still exhibit a pattern different to that of the component for reasons such as the participant being an outlier or that the pattern exhibited by the participant may be sufficiently unique that it was not captured by variation in modelling.

Would anyone have any comments or thoughts on this?